# Old cached image displays after clear local cache, want to display newly downloaded image from network

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my app I download an image from the network then save this image in local cache storage with a specific name such as `test.jpeg`, then I display the `test.jpeg` image in Android device.

If I clear local cache for the app in android settings, then again download new image from network and save the new image with the same name (`test.jpeg`). Then I display the image, I expect the new image should be displayed but it displayed the old image.

After killing the app and running it again then it displays the new image.

To download and save the image I use `Dio` library.

Here is sample code of download and save to local directory

```
Dio client;
String imageSavePath =
    path.join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, “test.jpeg”);
await  client.download(url, imageSavePath);
```

So, how can I display newly downloaded image without closing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/imageCache.html

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

imageCache.clear();
```

It might works for you.